# EXCEL - Formula to populate column with comments depending on logic of comparing the criteria over several other columns

Tags: excel, if-statement

Not sure if this is already answered and I've attempted using CONCATENATE and CHOOSE to make this nested IF statement formula to populate a Comments column correctly with a comment depending on multiple conditions using multiple IF statements.

The logic I have is as follows and is order of priority:

```
IF Z2(Date field) < 2021 AND is NOT BLANK AND AD2 is TRUE, then "Comment-1"
IF F2(Date field) < 2021 AND is NOT BLANK AND AD2 is FALSE, then "Comment-2"
IF G2(String) = "#-#", then "Comment-3"
IF G2(String) = "#", then "Comment-4"
IF F2(Date field) = BLANK then "Comment-5"
IF AG2(dollar amount) = negative number then "Comment-6"
IF O2(String) contains "ABC" then "Comment-7"
IF AG2(dollar amount) = BETWEEN -1 AND 1 then "Comment-8"
IF O2(String) contains "XYZ" then "Comment-9"
IF AH2(dollar amount) is negative then "Comment-10"
IF AH2(dollar amount) is positive then "Comment-11"
```

I have this:

```
=IF( AND( YEAR(Z2) < 2021, AD2=TRUE ), "comment1",
 IF( AND( YEAR(Z2) < 2021, AD2=FALSE ), "comment1",
 IF( AND( YEAR(F2) < 2021, AD2=TRUE ), "comment2",
 IF( AND( YEAR(F2) < 2021, AD2=FALSE ), "comment2",
 IF( G2="#-#", "comment3",
 IF( G2="#", "comment4",
 IF( ISBLANK(F2), "comment5",
 IF( AG2 > 0, "comment6",
 IF( ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "ABC", O2 ) ), "comment7",
 IF( AND( AG2 > -1, AG2 < 1 ), "comment8",
 IF( ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "XYZ", O2 ) ), "comment9",
 IF( AH2 > 0, "comment10",
 IF( AH2 < 0, "comment11",
     )))))))))))))
```

This returns most of the rows populated correctly, around 5000 out of 20000 are still incorrect.

I need help controlling for the is NOT BLANK for the first two IF statements, I think the logic is getting stuck on Z2 and F2 having a blank and so comment 1 or 2 is getting populated when these come back TRUE.

Any further light on this would be helpful.

EDIT: Reordered logic to what the priority of what should return

Comment: Sample data and expected outcomes would be useful here. For example do you expect is the output if `G2` is `#`, and `F2` is blank vs if `G2` is `#` and `F2` is a year after 2021?

Comment: There is over 20,000 rows so a sample piece isn't possible to cover all the different possibly scenarios of the provided conditions. 

I am working on gathering the requirements of what should take priority.

Comment: edited to reorder the logic in order of what is expected to be returned, have also edited provided nested IF statement to reflect new updates. got most rows to populate.

Comment: If you know Z and F are having blank values, why don't you include that requirement in your AND logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot:

```
=IF( AND( YEAR(Z2) < 2021, LEN(Z2) > 0, AD2=TRUE ), "comment1",
 IF( AND( YEAR(F2) < 2021, LEN(F2) > 0, AD2=FALSE ), "comment2",
 IF( G2="#-#", "comment3",
 IF( G2="#", "comment4",
 IF( ISBLANK(F2), "comment5",
 IF( AG2 < 0, "comment6",
 IF( ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "ABC", O2 ) ), "comment7",
 IF( AND( AG2 > -1, AG2 < 1 ), "comment8",
 IF( ISNUMBER( SEARCH( "XYZ", O2 ) ), "comment9",
 IF( AH2 < 0, "comment10",
 IF( AH2 > 0, "comment11", "NO COMMENT" )))))))))))
```

**Some Notes:**

- For comment 6, you had AG2 > 0, I changed that to AG2 < 0 to match your original requirements.
- For comment 10 and 11, you also had the lt/gt signs reversed.
- For comment 9, the rule will never fire for values between -1 and zero because comment 6 overrides that.
- Where I added a check for blank cells, I used `LEN() > 0` rather than `ISBLANK`, feel free to use ISBLANK. I added that as another condition in the `AND` clause for your first two comments.
- I added NO COMMENT when all conditions fall through.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt! Ultimately I was only able to get it to populate correctly for roughly 99% of the rows. I think the issue here is missing constraints or rules as to why those comments not returning should or should not take priority over others and needs more requirements gathering.

Comment: Hey, 99% is better than your original 75%. :-)  Yes, there are a lot of convoluted rules in place, it is easy to get conflicting conditionals. Always good to to confirm the requirements. Good luck.